# .bat file - output the value of a variable whose name is stored as a variable

Tags: variables, loops, batch-file, echo

Okay so as a part of a loop I am reading in an unknown number of file names, and saving them into variables whose name depends on the number of files in the folder. Like this:

```
SET /a count=1

DIR %rootFolder%> "fileList.txt" /b

FOR /f "tokens=* delims= usebackq" %%a IN ("fileList.txt") DO CALL :LOOP %%a
goto :LOOP2
:Loop
SET var=%1
SET File%count%=%var%
SET /a count=%count%+1
GOTO:EOF
```

this works fine

```
ECHO File1
ECHO File2
```

outputs

```
firstfile.txt
secondfile.txt
```

The problem I'm having is reading out the contents of the variable in a later loop because this code:

```
SET fileName=File%count%
ECHO %fileName%> temp.txt
```

outputs

```
File1
```

when I want it to output the value stored in the variable by that name.
Desired output:

```
firstfile.txt
```

Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this code can help you:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b %rootFolder%') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set File!count!=%%a
)

for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
    echo !File%%a!
)
```

And if you don't like shortcuts with !'s, you could achieve what you asked for with only %'s like:

```
set /a count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b %rootFolder%') do call :loop %%a
call set var=%%File%count%%%
echo %var%

goto :eof

:loop
set /a count+=1
set File%count%=%1
goto :eof
```

Comment: +1, Probably should add the /a-d option to the DIR command to restrict the output to files and eliminate folders. Also, this will fail if a filename contains `!` character.

Comment: For ! character you could use the workaround like set var=%var:!=^!%

Comment: There are lots of reasons why that won't help in this context: The value isn't in an environment variable yet; to get it there you have to expand %%a, and you are right back where you started. Also can't use %var% within the same code block that defines it, hence the need for delayed expansion in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
call echo %%fileName%% > temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The panda-34 solution will fail if a file name contains `!` because delayed expansion will corrupt the expansion of %%a. The solution can be improved to support `!` in file names by toggling delayed expansion on and off within the loop.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b %rootFolder%') do (
  set /a count+=1
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  for /f %%b in ("!count!") do (
    endlocal
    set "file%%b=%%a"
  )
)

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
  echo !File%%a!
)
```

In my mind the delayed expansion solution is by far the best approach. But there is another option.

```
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b %rootFolder%') do (
  set /a count+=1
  call set "file%%count%%=%%a"
)

for /l %%a in (1,1,%count%) do (
  call echo %%File%%a%%
)
```

The call solution looks simpler, but it is significantly slower, and it can fail if the expanded variable contains a special character like `&`.